# Tail -f piped through grep not outputing to file, but outputs to console

Tags: grep, tail, stdout

I'm using the following command

```
tail -f /mydir/myfile |  grep "searchterm" >> outfile
```

Without the `-f` it works fine, but with the `-f`, which I need, nothing is written to the file. The following outputs to the console just fine

```
tail -f /mydir/myfile |  grep "searchterm"
```

What do I need to do in order to get my command to correctly write out to a file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have GNU [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
tail -f /mydir/myfile |  grep --line-buffered "searchterm" >> outfile
```

Which will write every line, for a performance penalty.

Alternatively, wait for more output. If you're killing the processes, just kill the `tail` process and the buffer should flush before `grep` exits.

Comment: I will try this out first thing Monday and report back.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Is grep buffering the output perhaps, making it appear like there is none? Try:

```
tail -f /mydir/myfile | grep --line-buffered "searchterm" >> outfile
```