# Extract characters from a serial port

Tags: grep, pipe, serial-port

I have a dummy question for you, I am trying to extract some lines from a file beginning by a special string of characters and to copy them into a file. I tried :

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0 | grep "something" > essai
```

The file is created but it contains nothing!

Comment: Does the `cat /dev/ttyACM0` part work right? Often with serial ports you need to run `stty` to set the speed of the port to match the speed of the device attached to the port.

Comment: Yep, there is terminal outputs when i am not using  the '>'. It shows exactly whatbi want to save

Comment: It may be a matter of buffering: see similar questions [Tail -f piped through grep not outputing to file, but outputs to console](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65824/tail-f-piped-through-grep-not-outputing-to-file-but-outputs-to-console/65826#65826) and [Turn off buffering in pipe](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) for example

Comment: It's probably a buffering issue, then, since grep isn't going to stop reading until the serial port goes offline and will be storing up its output until either a few kilobytes has been amassed or it exits. On many systems you can give grep a `-m numberofmatches` argument so it'll quit after that number of matched lines. Can you describe any conditions for which grep should consider the file completely read, so it can quit?

Comment: Using dd instead of cat would take care of the buffering issue.

Comment: Try `grep --line-buffered < /dev/ttyACM0 > essai` - it should be line-buffered on both input and output.

Comment: Thank you mark Plot'ick it does work now. could you explain me what was the problem with the buffer?

Answer (score 3):

For efficiency, grep and many other commands use *buffered I/O*, that is, they read large blocks of data at once (rather than, say, one character at a time), and do not output data until a certain amount has been amassed (rather than, say, writing a line at a time or a character at a time)

But, when a program's input is from a terminal (such as your serial port), the operating system does the program a favor and returns a line at a time (the program can change this by putting the terminal into *raw* or [*noncanonical mode*](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html); most don't).

And when a program uses the [stdio](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stdin.html) library, standard output to a terminal (the documentation calls this an "interactive device") is, by default, line buffered, but output to a file or pipe is fully buffered.

A program using the stdio library can choose full buffering, line buffering, or no buffering by calling [`setvbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html). It can also call [`fflush`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flushing-Buffers.html) to force a write whenever it wishes.

GNU grep takes a [`--line-buffered`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Other-Options) option, which will run the [following code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c#n1148) in the function that outputs a matching line:

```
if (line_buffered)
  fflush (stdout);
```

---

Putting all the pieces together:

With this command:

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0 | grep "something" > essai
```

`cat` will read a line at a time from `/dev/ttyACM0`. After it has amassed a few kilobytes of output, it will write to the pipe. It will repeat this until the read returns a count of zero or fails (which probably won't happen until the serial port goes offline).

`grep` will read a few kilobytes at a time from the pipe, and after it has amassed a few kilobytes of output, it will write to the `essai` fle. It will repeat this until the read returns a count of zero or fails, which will happen if and when the `cat` process exits.

So you won't see anything appear in the `essai` file until `grep` has found a few kilobytes' worth of matching lines.

To get output written to the file more promptly, you can give GNU grep that option:

```
grep --line-buffered < /dev/ttyACM0 > essai
```

Since it's reading from a serial port, it will be line buffered, and the `--line-buffered` option will make output line buffered as well.